# Post and save Django variable, doesn´t work

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

could someone please check how should I write correctly the views.py part?

If I code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def shifts_table(request):
    print(request.POST['value'])        
    return render(request, 'shifts_table.html', {})
```

...at least the page runs, but if I code like below it doesn't, any idea why?

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages

def shifts_table(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        number = request.POST['value']
        if number.is_valid():
            number.save()   
            return redirect('shifts_table.html')
        else:
            messages.success(request, ('Seems Like There Was An Error...'))
            return render(request, 'home.html', {})
    else:       
        return render(request, 'shifts_table.html', {})
```

home.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'shifts_table' %}" method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for='number'>Number:</label>
    <input type="number" name="value" placeholder="2020" required><br/>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('shifts_table', views.shifts_table, name='shifts_table'),
]
```

Comment: *but if I code like below it doesn't* - what *does* happen when you run that code?

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  .... and like I commented to our colleague Amine, I would like to submit any number, post it and save as a temporal variable 'number' to do some simple calculations in other.py (in a future). Is it possible to post an integer and save it without creating objects and models?

Comment: You can’t set a variable in one request and access it in another. You could save data in the session, or a cookie, or a cache, then refetch it in another view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save a variable you can simply use sessions

```
request.session['number'] = number
```

Then you can use request.session['number'] like any other variable

Answer (score 0):

```
number = request.POST['value']
```

This will return a string and strings don't have a save method so it will not work

I think that you have a model that is referenced by that number and to save it to the database you can do something like this

```
object= yourmodel.objects.get(pk=number)
object.save()
```

Also strings don't have a definition for is_valid(), which is used in forms, which are not implemented in your view

After saving to the database you have to redirect, which is done only if nothing is submitted

Final code :

```
def shifts_table(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        number = request.POST['value']
        # check if number is valid (not empty and no spaces before or after)
        if not number.strip(): 
            object = yourmodel.objects.get(pk=number)
            object.save()
            return render(request, 'home.html', {})
        else:
            messages.success(request, ('Seems Like There Was An Error...'))
            return render(request, 'home.html', {})
    else:       
        return render(request, 'shifts_table.html', {})
```

Comment: Hi Amine, I just want to submit any number, post it and save as a temporal variable 'number' to do some simple calculations in other.py (in a future). Is it possible to post an integer and save it without objects and models?

Comment: Please see my other answer